# update the first character in the column, in queries oracle

Tags: sql, string, oracle, oracle11g, sql-update

I have an "Invoices" table. The table is 190 thousand rows. But there is a problem. In the column "Docnumber" all records of this format "Y-1000", "Y-1001" and I want to bond in all records from Y to P. That there were all records of this format "P-1000", "P-1001". But I do not understand how to do it right, I will be grateful for the help!

Comment: Take a look at the `REPLACE` function.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions153.htm#SQLRF00697

Comment: @APC all these doc number values start with 'Y-'!)

Answer (score 4):

You can use string functions. The following replaces the first character of every value in the column with `'P'`:

```
update mytable t set docnumber = 'P' || substr(docnumber, 2)
```

Depending on your actual requirement, you can be a little more specific, for example by ensuring that `docnumber` starts with `'Y'`:

```
update mytable t set docnumber = 'P' || substr(docnumber, 2) 
where docnumber like 'Y%'
```

Comment: The Seeker wants to change `Y-1001` to `P-1001`, not the other way round :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple replace of `Y` to `P` in the column. So a simple update with the `REPLACE` function will solve the problem.

```
UPDATE invoices
SET docnumber = REPLACE (docnumber, 'Y', 'P');
```

Of course this assumes that the rest of the string cannot contain a `P`. If it can, then a regular expression based replace will work using the `REGEXP_REPLACE`function which will only replace the beginning `Y`.

```
UPDATE invoices
SET docnumber = REGEXP_REPLACE (docnumber, '^Y', 'P');
```

The following query shows that `REGEXP_REPLACE` only replaces the beginning `Y`

```
WITH
    inv
    AS
        (SELECT 'Y-8817Y' AS docnumber FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 'Y-8884' AS docnumber FROM DUAL)
SELECT docnumber,
       REGEXP_REPLACE (docnumber, '^Y', 'P') AS replaced_y
FROM inv;
```

This is the result:

```
DOCNUMBER   REPLACED_Y
Y-8817Y     P-8817Y
Y-8884      P-8884
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query:

```
update Invoice_test set docnumber = 'P'||SUBSTR(DOCNUMBER, 2) where SUBSTR(DOCNUMBER, 1,1) = 'Y';
```